# Hot deployment of class files in jboss

Tags: java, jboss-4.2.x, hotdeploy

Hot deployment of class files in jBoss.

Can any please help me in hot deploying the java class files without restarting the server again and again?
JBoss version 4.2.3 GA

I'm a novice to this field, so basic help is appreciated.

Comment: @KennethClark - The post mentioned about updating the timestamp of web.xml. 

Will this redeploy the update class files in X.jar in JBoss shared lib folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, you can do this.
This only redeploy your project.

[image]

Comment: Will this redeploy the update class files in X.jar in JBoss shared lib folder?